# Fetching a Localized Global as a Static Translation Causes Error in How Plugins Load

Tags: templating, localization

I've extended all my "translations/[locale_id].php" to refer to this  function which enables us to put all our translations under a global in the control-panel.

However, when this is done – we lose data attached to our assets. We currently use a Focal Point plugin attached to our assets. It describes with a field how images are to be cropped. This particular plugin stops working when the line highlighted below is executed.

```
function get_dynamic_translations() {
    $translations = array();

    if (!craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
        // the following line makes the plugin "FocalPointField" stop loading its data
        $i18n = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('i18n');

        foreach ($i18n->getFieldValue('translations') as $current_block) {
            $translations[$current_block->content->key] = $current_block->content->value;
        }
    }

    return $translations;


}
```

I would love for these two solutions to work together in perfect harmony – but I can't seem to figure out why this is not working.

Do you have any idea how I can go forth?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```php
$current_criteria->fieldId = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('translations');
```

should probably have a `->id` at the end?

```php
$current_criteria->fieldId = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('translations')->id;
```

But the whole code could probably be replaced with:

```php
function get_dynamic_translations() {
    $translations = array();

    if (!craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {

        $i18n = craft()->globals->getSetByHandle('i18n');

        foreach ($i18n->getFieldValue('translations') as $current_block) {
            $translations[$current_block->content->key] = $current_block->content->value;
        }
    }

    return $translations;
}
```

Comment: Implementing this function causes the following error: 

-> Undefined property: Craft\GlobalSetModel::$translations

Ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: @KristianS.Munkvold my assumption was that there is a `translations` field handle on your `i18n` global set - is that right?

Comment: In addition – The main problem here is that this code interferes with how  plugins are loaded. I am unable to extract data from Custom Fields. Do you know why?

Comment: Updated code in main question to reflect this solution. Main problem is still not fixed.

Comment: @KristianS.MunkvoldI just tested this locally and it worked as expected. So it’s probably something simple like a typo in one of your field handles.

Comment: – There's no typo and I got it working. Could you read through my question once more? 

I'm still struggling with the fact that Fetching a Localized Global as a Static Translation Causes Error in How Plugins Load.